# Reading specific Google calendar entry

Tags: android, call, google-calendar-api

I am beginner android developer.
I have got a time of call:

```
Cursor callCur = getContentResolver().query(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,null);
int callDateIn = callCur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE);
long callDate = new Long(callCur.getLong(callDateIn));
```

Now need to check this time (`long callDate`) in Google Calendar, if there is any entry (with same time).
How can I do it please?

Answer (score 0):

There is no calendar in the Android OS.

If you mean the user's Google Calendar, use the [Google Calendar GData API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/).

If you mean some other calendar, contact that calendar's developers to see what API options there are.